# How do I protect a cell in google sheets after they are edited, and then unprotect when they are empty again?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is the code I have running so far:

```
function onEdit(e){
  let protection = e.range.protect();
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit())  {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
   }
}
```

This locks the cells after they are edited, however even after the cell has been emptied, the cell remains locked to only the one editor. How can I make this change so that if it is empty again it will unprotect itself?

Thanks so much!

Comment: in case anyone else has this issue= here is the answer.

Comment: }function onEdit(e){
  if (e.value == null){
    let prot = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    for (let i in prot){
      if (prot[i].getRange().getA1Notation() == e.range.getA1Notation())
        prot[i].remove();
    }
  } else {
    let protection = e.range.protect();
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    if (protection.canDomainEdit())
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}

Comment: this is the missing code

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to my own question :

(Why did I create this function. I am using Google Sheets to create a schedule with 50+ users. The users are able to select their preferences and write their name in the schedule. Then once protected, their name cannot be removed from the schedule except by themselves.)

--This can be added to the sheet using "App script" extension.

Below is the code. The first half protects the cell after edit. Only the user (and admin) can edit the cell once it is edited. After edit, it remains protected against change by all others. Then, the second half removes the protection once the user deletes the contents of the cell. This will cause the cell to be available once again for use by another user.

This code produces a cycle, upon edit by a user it is protected, and upon deletion by the user the protection is removed.

`````
`function onEdit(e){
let protection = e.range.protect();
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit())  {
protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}
}function onEdit(e){
if (e.value == null){
  let prot = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (let i in prot){
    if (prot[i].getRange().getA1Notation() == e.range.getA1Notation())
      prot[i].remove();
  }
} else {
  let protection = e.range.protect();
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit())
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}
}
````
`````